# Make inner query to delete duplicated code

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have redshift script, where I have duplicated code

Here is script

```
    SELECT  
       CASE
              WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >120 THEN '120 + Days'
              WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >90 THEN '90 - 120 Days'
              WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >60 THEN '60 - 90 Days'
              WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >30 THEN '30 - 60 Days'
              WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) IS NULL THEN '90 + Days'
              ELSE '0 - 30 Days'
       END AS OpenedAging,
       be.ClientId,
       cc.FullName AS ClientName,
       SUM(CASE
              WHEN (bes.UseAgreedView) = 1 THEN a.ChargeTotalAgreed
              ELSE a.ChargeTotal
       END - a.PaymentAdjustment - a.PaymentAmount) AS Owed
FROM    public.billing_entries be
LEFT JOIN
       (
       SELECT  bed.BillingEntryId,
               bed.PaymentCount,
               bed.PaymentRegular,
               bed.Copay,
               bed.ChargeTotal,
               bed.ChargeTotalAgreed,
               bed.PaymentAdjustment,
               bed.PaymentRegular + bed.PaymentCopay - bed.PaymentAdjustment AS PaymentAmount
       FROM    public.billing_entry_dimensions bed
       ) a
ON      a.BillingEntryId = be.Id
LEFT JOIN
       public.billing_settings bes
ON     bes.OrganizationId = be.OrganizationId
LEFT JOIN
       public.contact_insurances cic
ON     cic.Id = be.insuranceId
LEFT JOIN
       public.insurance ic
ON     ic.Id = cic.InsuranceCompanyId
LEFT JOIN
       public.contact_addresses ca
ON     ca.Id = be.ClientLocationId

LEFT JOIN       
       public.contacts cc
ON     cc.Id = be.ClientId

WHERE   be.OrganizationId = 65277
       AND be.IsVoid IS NULL
       AND be.IsDeleted IS NULL

GROUP BY        
       CASE
       WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >120 THEN '120 + Days'
       WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >90 THEN '90 - 120 Days'
       WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >60 THEN '60 - 90 Days'
       WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >30 THEN '30 - 60 Days'
              WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) IS NULL THEN '90 + Days'
              ELSE '0 - 30 Days'
       END,
       be.ClientId,
       cc.FullName
```

**As you see I have this code duplicated at SELECT and in GROUP BY**

> CASE
>                 WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >120 THEN '120 + Days'
>                 WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >90 THEN '90 - 120 Days'
>                 WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >60 THEN '60 - 90 Days'
>                 WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >30 THEN '30 - 60 Days'
>                 WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) IS NULL THEN '90 + Days'
>                 ELSE '0 - 30 Days'
>          END

How I can make it inner query and alias it in SELECT and GROUP BY correctly?

Comment: Have you tried using an additional table with ranges instead of hardcoding the `case` expression? You can likely create that table as CTE like `with OpenedAgingRanges (from,to,display) as (select 0,30,'' union all select 30,60,'30-60 Days') union all ... ) select ..., r.display from ... left join OpenedAgingRanges r on DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >= r.from and DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) < r.to `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, an alias defined in a `SELECT` clause isn't visible to a `GROUP BY` clause at the same level.  The only option which comes to mind would be to wrap your current query in a CTE, and then subquery it with aggregation, reusing the alias in the `CASE` expression:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  
        CASE
            WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >120 THEN '120 + Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >90 THEN '90 - 120 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >60 THEN '60 - 90 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) >30 THEN '30 - 60 Days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(Day,CONVERT(DATE,be.timeWorkedFrom),GETDATE()) IS NULL THEN '90 + Days'
            ELSE '0 - 30 Days'
        END AS OpenedAging,
        be.ClientId,
        cc.FullName AS ClientName,
        bes.UseAgreedView,
        a.ChargeTotalAgreed,
        a.ChargeTotal,
        a.PaymentAdjustment,
        a.PaymentAmount
    FROM public.billing_entries be
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            bed.BillingEntryId,
            bed.PaymentCount,
            bed.PaymentRegular,
            bed.Copay,
            bed.ChargeTotal,
            bed.ChargeTotalAgreed,
            bed.PaymentAdjustment,
            bed.PaymentRegular + bed.PaymentCopay - bed.PaymentAdjustment AS PaymentAmount
        FROM public.billing_entry_dimensions bed
    ) a
        ON a.BillingEntryId = be.Id
    LEFT JOIN public.billing_settings bes
        ON bes.OrganizationId = be.OrganizationId
    LEFT JOIN public.contact_insurances cic
        ON cic.Id = be.insuranceId
    LEFT JOIN public.insurance ic
        ON ic.Id = cic.InsuranceCompanyId
    LEFT JOIN public.contact_addresses ca
        ON ca.Id = be.ClientLocationId
    LEFT JOIN public.contacts cc
        ON cc.Id = be.ClientId
    WHERE
        be.OrganizationId = 65277 AND
        be.IsVoid IS NULL         AND
        be.IsDeleted IS NULL
)
```

And here is the actual query using the above CTE:

```
SELECT  
    OpenedAging,
    ClientId,
    ClientName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN UseAgreedView = 1
             THEN ChargeTotalAgreed
             ELSE a.ChargeTotal END - PaymentAdjustment - PaymentAmount) AS Owed
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    OpenedAging,
    ClientId,
    ClientName;
```

Comment: Hm. Great thing. Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You can do `group by 1,2,3`, the numbers here stand for the indexes in your column list. Basically, you'll be referencing your CASE statement and two other columns like this.